# Append strings to a text in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to classify some characters that fulfill a condition in one column and concatenate the other characters in a string in another column.

The classification is working. When there is a 1 in the column "col", the program has to compare the inputs in "Category", the actual value with the previous one. If the priority number is smaller, save the value in "AlarmPrior", and the other value in "Other Alarms". I want to concatenate all the values with less priority in a string in "Other Alarms".

```r
    #test the function 

    col <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    Priority <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    Category <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
    eventlog_overlap.dt <- data.table(col,Priority, IEC_category)

    #loading the libraries
    library(magrittr) 
    library(dplyr)

    #comparison and value assignation in function of the priority

    eventlog_overlap.dt$OtherAlarms <- "" 
    eventlog_overlap.dt <- 
      eventlog_overlap.dt %>% 
        mutate(AlarmPrior = ifelse(col == 1,
                                      ifelse(Priority <= lag(Priority), 
                                               Category, 
                                               lag(Category)), NA),
               OtherAlarms = ifelse(col == 1,
                                    ifelse(Priority <= lag(Priority),
                                               "1",
                                               paste0(sprintf(Category,     lag(OtherAlarms)), collapse = ", ")),NA))
```

For example:

This input,

```
col <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
Priority <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Category <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
```

Should return:

```r
             col      Priority      Category     OtherAlarms     AlarmPrior
    1         0          1             a             NA             NA
    2         1          2             b             b               a             
    3         0          3             c             b,c             NA
    4         0          4             d             b,c             NA
    5         1          5             e             b,c,e           d
    6         1          6             f             b,c,e,f         e
```

My actual result is this one:

```r
             col      Priority      Category     OtherAlarms     AlarmPrior
    1         0          1             a             NA             NA
    2         1          2             b             a,b,c,d,e,f     a             
    3         0          3             c             NA              NA
    4         0          4             d             NA              NA
    5         1          5             e             a,b,c,d,e,f     d
    6         1          6             f             a,b,c,d,e,f     e
```

Comment: try `sprintf(Category[-1], lag(OtherAlarms[-1])`. BTW you confused `OtherAlarms` and `AlarmPrior` as variable names in `mutate`.

Comment: @jay.sf, this solution doesn't fit my problem. How should I configure mutate? I'm new with R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `for` statement to solve the problem

```
col <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
Priority <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Category <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
eventlog_overlap.dt <- data.table(col,Priority, Category)

#loading the libraries
library(magrittr) 
library(dplyr)

#comparison and value assignation in function of the priority

eventlog_overlap.dt$OtherAlarms <- "" 
eventlog_overlap.dt <- 
  eventlog_overlap.dt %>%
  mutate(AlarmPrior = ifelse(col == 1,
                             ifelse(Priority <= lag(Priority), 
                                    Category, 
                                    lag(Category)), NA))



eventlog_overlap.dt$leadCate= lead(eventlog_overlap.dt$AlarmPrior)

tmpdata = character()
eventlog_overlap.dt$tmp= NA
for(i in 1:nrow(eventlog_overlap.dt)){

  tmp =  eventlog_overlap.dt[i,3]
  leadtmp = eventlog_overlap.dt[i,6]

  if(!is.na(leadtmp == tmp) & !as.logical(eventlog_overlap.dt$col[i])){

    tmp = tmp[!grepl(tmp,leadtmp)]
    tmp = ifelse(NROW(tmp)==0,NA,tmp)
    tmpdata = tmpdata
  } else{
    tmpdata = c(tmpdata,tmp)
  }

  eventlog_overlap.dt[i,7] = paste(tmpdata,collapse = ',')
 }
```

And the result is shown below

```
> eventlog_overlap.dt

  col Priority Category OtherAlarms AlarmPrior leadCate     tmp
1
1   0        1        a                   <NA>        a        
2
2   1        2        b                      a     <NA>       b
3
3   0        3        c                   <NA>     <NA>     b,c
4
4   0        4        d                   <NA>        d     b,c
5
5   1        5        e                      d        e   b,c,e
6
6   1        6        f                      e     <NA> b,c,e,f
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve Lee, but here comes another question. Is the for loop efficient in R? I read about it and people say that it's slow.

Comment: I obtain only NA values in the column tmp, and I've only copied your code.

Comment: In fact, the for loops in R have been made a lot more performant and are currently at least as fast as then other method.

Comment: And i added `}` to closed the for loop